# My AWS access key id and secret key - keep changing

Tags: amazon-web-services

The organization I work for has AWS integrated with Azure AD, so I access AWS management console using a link from office.com (after I login using my org credentials).

Once I login, I see I have "command line or programmatic access" at a "SessionManager" level. So I can get the access key and secret key from the browser console. But when I use this access key id and secret key from a command line out side of the browser based AWS mgmt console, I get invalid credentials error.

What do I need to gain access from a command line outside of the browser based AWS mgmt console? Do I need access as IAM user?

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example of how you're using the access and secret key on the command line ?

Comment: I added the access key id and secret key in the credentials file.

Comment: I used 'aws configure' to add the access key and secret key. And then I tried 'aws ec2 describe-instances'. I get the invalid credentials error.